# Работа с подключенной библиотекой

Tags: java

Всем добрый день!
Задание:

1. скачать и подключить внешнюю библиотеку
2. получить список из библиотеки (выдается список моделей самолетов)
3. посчитать количество моделей из этого списка (вывести число int)

Библиотеку скачал, подключил, вывел список моделей самолетов. Подскажите как подсчитать кол-во моделей из этого списка?

```
import com.skillbox.airport.Airport;

    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            //список моделей самолетов
            Airport airport = Airport.getInstance();

            System.out.println(airport.getAllAircrafts());
        }
    }
```

Вот такой список получается после запроса

```
[Boeing 777-200, Boeing 737-800, Boeing 777-200, Boeing 777-200, Airbus A-321, Boeing 737-200, Boeing 737-200, Airbus A-320, Airbus A-319, Airbus A-320, Boeing 777-200, Airbus A-320, Airbus A-321, Boeing 737-200, Airbus A-321, Airbus A-321, Boeing 737-200]
```

Comment: для подсчета количества моделей либо нужно знать, какой тип возвращает `airport.getAllAircrafts()`,  либо использовать регулярные выражения

Comment: @АлексейОсецкий При запросе возвращает массив

Comment: статический массив, или один из типов коллекции, например `List,ArrayList`?

Comment: @АлексейОсецкий Если я правильно понимаю то List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подсчет количества моделей из списка

```
//метод size стандартный метод для интерфейса List, 
//чтобы узнать размер элементов в списке
airport.getAllAircrafts().size();
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо! Все работает!